# "Type=cdir;Modify..." on WooCommerce Products Pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm creating a web-shop using WooCommerce and there is this annoying text on the bottom of every page that includes the display of products:

```
Type=cdir;Modify=20150130131452;Unique=04c8002602430d11;Perm=cmpdfe;UNIX.mode=0755;UNIX.owner=2214475;UNIX.group=1110; . Type=pdir;Modify=20150130131452;Unique=04c80026027ea1c6;Perm=cmpdfe;UNIX.mode=0755;UNIX.owner=2214475;UNIX.group=1110; ..
```

When inspecting the sourcecode, I see that the text is within a div with the class `products` (the div contains several divs of the class `row` and then there is the annoying text just at the end of the div).

Can anyone tell me how to remove the text from my product pages?

- Is there a template maybe that is responsible for adding the text? (What template is responsible for the div with the class `products`?)
- Is there a php command that i can include in my functions.php located in my child-theme to remove the text? (I tried `str_ireplace` but it did not work)

Thanks

Comment: It looks like a debug information: Check under Admin menu > WooCommerce > System status > Tools (tab), if debug mode id not enabled. May be it could be too some debug mode on a plugin or Wordpress itself

Comment: Debug mode is not active.

I searched on the topic quite a bit and it seems like there went something wrong during the installation and the only known solution so far is to reinstall everything (wordpress, woocommerce and plugins). However, a new installation would be too much work right now, so I'm wondering if there might be another way...

Comment: you are certainly right, sorry